# How to handle variables in loops from functions and functions in regards to garbage collector?

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, garbage-collection

I'm trying to create my little particle system as a self study to learn more about javascript. Althought I'm not a complete beginner to programming I'm anything but professional programmer. Currently I'm trying to advance my knowledge of pure javascript (thus no libraries in my code).

After reading an article by google, and many others, I found myself perplexed because of garbage collection. According to the article, memory chart, compared to my program's, should look more smoother and GC shouldn't be called that often too. Below is link to screenshot from google chromes developer tools.

There are two things I'd like to ask you and I'd appreciate any insight from you.

**a/ Could this kind of behaviour be possibly the result of calling var inside functions for loop indexing?**

Example:

```
function doSomething(args) {
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {/*some code*/}
}
```

My animation loop calls different functions very often (requestanimationframe). How do you deal with these variables which are used by loops (var i)?
Declaring them outside as globals? But that gets quite ugly if you get nested loops from different function calls.

**b/ Does assigning functions to variables influences memory stacking (creating new functions on run)?**

In an article I found that assigning function to variable prevents creating new functions on every function call.
I tried assigning all my functions to variables and calling them this way but sadly it didn't change anything (performance, memory chart).

Fiddle (linke below) of my whole current little particle system with a test scene. There is about 8700 particles on screen, with my super slow processor it runs at constant 32 fps.
With quad-core processor I get 54-60 fps depending on settings (60 fps if I don't draw still objects as generators, attractors, ...).

But I periodicaly get slight choppiness when I run it so I'd like to be more effecient with my code and tweak it. But methods I found didn't work for me. Luckily since the beginning I was recycling particle objects so after getting to above mentioned 8700 particles I almost don't create any new objects with new Constructor.

So I'd like to kindly ask for your advice.

Thank you very much for reading this far :-).

Other links:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kwgp7kmh/1/

Memory chart from chrome dev tools: http://postimg.org/image/wl7pm4zzp/

Comment: Links to articles. Google one:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling;

Article1: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/static-mem-pools/;

Article2: https://www.scirra.com/blog/76/how-to-write-low-garbage-real-time-javascript

Comment: Generally, you want to define variables outside of the for loop. Hoisting it is easy, you can just do something simple like: http://jsfiddle.net/jmy05rxs/1/

Additionally, for-loops are blocking. If you are looping over large quantities of data, you might want to do something like setInterval instead (which pushes the function call out of the event loop). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jmy05rxs/2/

Comment: #1 - Premature optimization is a huge waste of time and complexity.  #2 - Only even consider working on GC optimization if you actually have a measured problem that you know is related to GC and you can measure where a problem is occurring and can measure the effect of making changes to your code.  All that said, move any code that doesn't absolutely have to be in a loop out of the loop.

Comment: You can also try to debug bottlenecks with `console.time('some_id')` / `console.timeEnd('some_id');
Check it: http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/jmy05rxs/3/

Comment: Your `unshift` operation may be generating a lot of garbage - in most implementations it's faster to append an element to an array (in this case via `push`) than to prepend an element, where the latter may require the allocation of a new array followed by an array copy.  See [this comparison](http://jsperf.com/push-pop-vs-unshift-shift/3) of `unshift` vs `push`.  In other words, if possible try to refactor your `unshift` operations into `push` operations.

Comment: To TheIronDeveloper - I understand that in loops there should be only things which are needed there. But isn't defining var i before loop in the function same as defining it as for(var i = 0; ...)? I can't see the difference. Could you extend the topic of setinterval for looping over array? I don't see the merits of it. I'm looping over array and using each property of the array for all the logic in the loop, so what exactly is the difference here when I can't move any further in this loop until I get that property and finish calculations with it?

Comment: To TheIronDeveloper: What I meant by defining indexing vars for loops in functions was this: function withLoop{for(var i)} RAF(withLoop); this way RAF calls function in my animation loop. Let's say I let the animation play for a minute at 60 fps so withLoop function gets called 60 times per second, that's 360 times per minute which means that there's 360 times created variable i and also 360 deleted, same with the function. Isn't this overusing memory allocation/deallocation?
I'm sorry if I don't get it I came from language where I was taking care of every allocation and deallocation.

Comment: To TheIronDeveloper: Definitely thank you for your advice, I highly appreciate it. So I'll care less about GC before finishing the whole thing and optimising it that way later. Since I'm used to work with memory it's quite unusual not to care about it that seriously now in javascript xD. Again thanks a lot.

Comment: Zim-Zam O'Pootertoot
Thanks, I don't even know why I changed it from push to unshift, atfter seeing that test I'm definitely gonna change it to push it seems like a huge wrong doing on my part :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever faced with some issues with performances, use a profiler.
Here i saw that it wad `action()` that was to blame, using 32% of the CPU.
The code of action is too generic, yet with 3 separate cases, which makes it hard to read and lowers its performances. By writing it more clearly, i go from 32% CPU to 3% CPU !!!!

```
// execute an action
// list: generate, attract, draw
function action(actions, arr, addParticles, arg2) {
    if (actions == 'draw') {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i].draw();
        }
        return;
    } else if ('generate' in actions) {
        if (addParticles) {                
            var generators = actions['generate'];
            for (var i = 0; i < generators.length; i++) {
                 generators[i].generate(arr);
            }
        }
    }
    var attractors = actions['attract'];
    if (attractors) {
        for (var j = 0; j < attractors.length; j++) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.lives; i++) {
                attractors[j].attract(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    var repulsors = actions['repulse'];
    if (repulsors) {
        for (var j = 0; j < repulsors.length; j++) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.lives; i++) {
                repulsors[j].repulse(arr[i], arg2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

move can gain a bit with a little easy caching.

the draw of the particle was done in update (fixed) + some other fixes made your app more fluid :

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/kwgp7kmh/3/

Edit :
The code above is way faster because it will be compiled by the Javascript engine that will assume (which is right) every array contains only objects of the same kind. So the cost will be closer to the cost of the same C++ code.
On the other hand, when writing :

```
 actions[prop][j][prop](arr[i], arg1, arg2);
```

every time the engine will perform all operations : read `prop` and `actions`, retrieve `prop[actions]` (1), retrieve its `j`-th element (2), retrieve the prop method of this element (3), retrieve arr[i] (4); then call, 4 costly operations that can't use type assumptions to be optimized. You have to write a code quite 'obvious' for the engine to be able to optimize it.

Comment: I see that even though you added vars in functions it didn't lead to anything I was afraid of after reading above mentioned articles. At first I had action written as separate cases but after adding more different objects I changed it to the generic one. I'm getting used to profiler these days. Thank you very much for all your time you spent on this it really helped me ever more than I anticipated!

Comment: Emmotionaly: Wow. Like really wow. Didn't expect anyone to go through the code and even make it better. I've finally found out how my parents felt when, as a kid, I was 'dissecting' the food they spent so much time preparing for me. Though, unlike them I really appreciate it! :-). Thanks a lot!

Comment: var will take time, but nothing that compares to the 4 undirections of actions[prop][j][prop](arr[i], arg1, arg2); you do in one of your for loop. You might have a look here https://github.com/gamealchemist/JSparkle to see my best efforts to optimize a particle engine. I'm glad you appreciated my dissection, Happy coding to you !

Comment: Oh lord, too fast, it's too fast! This will take a while to climb up to, thanks for your link nice work :-).

Comment: To GameAlchemist: One last question please. What exactly is wrong with actions[prop][j][prop](arr[i], arg1, arg2). I thought that more overheat comes from for (var prop in actions), because it forces a loop through a whole object and check for ownProperty, which seems redundant to do every function call when I know what I'm looking for. But I don't understand what you meant by '.. 4 undirections of ..'? Can you please extend that for me? Thank you very much.